# Google Code SVN checkin error

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I am getting the following error when trying to check in my code:

```
$> sudo svn commit --username <my username>
   svn: Commit failed (details follow):
   svn: access to '/svn/!svn/act/<a guid>' forbidden
```

It is a new project. I have read lots about casing, but I have simply coppied the checkout statement from the Goggle Code website and added a folder.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with SVN version 1.6.17 from the terminal.

Thank you all very much for your help,

Richard Hughes

Comment: Do you have more details about the command line you're trying to execute?

Comment: Forgive the simplicity - sudo svn commit --username <my username>

Comment: Do you have the same error message when calling `svn status`?

Comment: That gives me: A       trunk
'trunk' being the folder I am checking in

Comment: Can you try to run a `svn cleanup` first? And what output do you have with an `svn update`?

Comment: svn cleanup is OK. svn update returns 'At revision 0.'

Comment: Have you verified that you have write permissions and that you have entered your username and password correctly?

Comment: I should have write permissions as I created the project on Google Code. The username and password are as they are given on Google Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937159/svn-erroraccess-to-svn-myservice-svn-act-d99e498e-9a8d-374c-a3e4-fde21198bfa) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572575/svn-error-when-commiting-access-denied-foobar-mkactivity-myrepo), I would say you should verify the casing used when you first checked out the repository.

Comment: I don't understand what this means to be honest, as I simply coppied the SVN checkout command from the Google Code page

Comment: Can you give the link to this page?

Comment: You won't be able to commit changes using an anonymous account as it is stated on the page you've mentionned: `# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.` BTW, if you are the project owner, try to remove `superfarm-read-only` from the command line...

Comment: I'm not sure if you can see it, but there is also another box above that one with this: svn checkout https://superfarm.googlecode.com/svn/ superfarm --username <my username>

Comment: Did you add any file or folder before trying to commit?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13052/discussion-between-yannick-blondeau-and-rhughes)

Comment: The reason for the error was the email address I was using was not added as a project owner - the @gmail.com account was rather than my actual account. Thanks to Yannick Blondeau for the help!