# Why is subversion using system-name as username when running as system user?

Tags: maven, svn, teamcity

This has got me the whole day digging for answers. The bottom line is that when I run svn as system user it seems to use the system-name to authenticate against the SVN server regardless of what credentials are passed. Following is the long explanation that made arrive at that conclusion.

When running from a Windows 7 Professional, if I run `svn` from the console under any normal user, the application works as expected: if credentials have been cached in `%AppData%/Roaming/Subversion` it will use them, if not it will prompt for username and password unless I use the options `--username` and `--password`. If I enter credentials using the options then the commit works with no problem. All good so far.

But when I try to run `svn` as the system user (`nt authority\system`) in the same computer, it behaves differently. To begin with, `%AppData%/Roaming/Subversion` points to `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Subversion`, and I make sure there is no `auth` folder there, so no credentials cached. Then I run `svn` without any parameters and it doesn't prompt for username/password, instead it executes the action and receives an error from subversion:

```
svn: E175013: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175013: MKACTIVITY of '/svn/Development/!svn/act/f20db493-48f1-9c43-a957-541584be555e': 403 Forbidden (http://<ip-address>)
```

If I run it indicating `--username` and `--password`, it gets the same error. But then I check the error logs from subversion and find this:

```
[Fri Aug 08 17:32:18 2014] [error] [client <client IP>] Access denied: '<clienthostname>$' MKACTIVITY Development:
[Fri Aug 08 17:32:18 2014] [error] [client <client IP>] Access denied: '<clienthostname>$' DELETE Development:
```

Where `<clienthostname>` is the hostname of the computer where I'm trying to commit from (note the '$' at the end of the subversion log, that's not part of the hostname but it does appear in the log as part of the username).

So that's the question: why is `svn` behaving differently when running as system user? Why does it use the hostname as username when authenticating against the SVN server? And why do other users work correctly?

**Note:** I believe my problem is different from the following questions in stackoverflow:

- [Subversion ignoring “--password” and “--username” options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687/subversion-ignoring-password-and-username-options): I don't get any prompts to enter username and password, regardless of whether I indicate the options `--username` and `--password` or I don't
- [SVN Error when commiting Access denied: 'foobar' MKACTIVITY MYREPO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572575/svn-error-when-commiting-access-denied-foobar-mkactivity-myrepo): I saw this question and I tried double checking the case of all the items in the URL, no luck.
- [svn: MKACTIVITY 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032209/svn-mkactivity-403-forbidden): I have checked that no credentials are cached in `%AppData%/Roaming/Subversion`

---

For those who are wondering why I'm trying to run `svn` as system user, the answer is that I am trying to make a commit from TeamCity, which means it is the Build Agent the one executing the `svn` command. The Build Agent is a Windows Service and runs as system user, and the `svn` command fails in the way explained above.

Comment: What Subversion server do you use? SVN+HTTPD what version?

Comment: The Subversion server is version 1.6.5 (r38866). The client uses working copy version 1.8. Http Apache version Apache/2.2.8 (Win32).

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the **"--no-auth-cache"** in your svn commands and you won't see this issues. You might however run into other set of issues.

If you do not use the no-auth-cache it tries to figure out default username and password anyways

1. A better way would be to create a .subversion folder and store the authentication in that folder. So for the system account, you can specify a differrent userid and password for the login.

Comment: Thanks. I already use `--no-auth-cache`, forgot to mention that. In any case, I checked that there are no cached authentication in the file system, so I don't think that's the issue.